# Problemas na versão para Android

Tags: javascript, unity3d

Estou com problemas em um projeto. Configurei um botao para ligar e desligar os sons, funciona no pc, mas quando coloco no celular ele só funciona se eu clicar em dois locais ao mesmo tempo no touch, se eu clicar apenas no botão ele reconhece o toque, mas tipo (desliga e liga o som novamente)...

```
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        som = true;
        gameObject.GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
        player_controle.ativarSom = 2;
        som = false;

    break;
```

---

```
if (ativarSom > 1){
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("caso1");
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("caso2");
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("caso3");
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("caso4");
    som *= -1;
    ativarSom = 1;

}

if(som == 1 && efeitos == 1){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("caso1", acustica);

}

if(som == 1 && efeitos < 1){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("caso2", acustica);

}
```